# PySpark throwing ParseException for syntactical correct Hive Query

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I got a DDL query that works fine within beeline, but when I try to run the same query within a sparkSession it throws a parse Exception.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext

# Initialise Hive metastore
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://localhsost:9083")

# Create Spark Session
sparkSession = (SparkSession\
                .builder\
                .appName('test_case')\
                .enableHiveSupport()\
                .getOrCreate())



sparkSession.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE B LIKE A")
```

Pyspark Exception:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'LIKE' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 53)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE EXTERNAL TABLE B LIKE A\n-----------------------------------------------------^^^\n"
```

How Can I make the hiveQL function work within pySpark?
The problem seems to be that the query is executed like a SparkSQL-Query and not like a HiveQL-Query, even though I got enableHiveSupport activated for the sparkSession.

Comment: same Exception happening

Comment: I can not replicate this error but try this other workaround: `sparkSession.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE B AS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE 1=0)")`

Comment: Try running something like `sparkSession.sql("use name_of_target_hive_db")` before you try running your query.

Comment: None of this worked for me. As mentioned, the query is valid HQL syntax and never fails within beeline. Hive Support still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL queries use SparkSQL by default. To enable HiveQL syntax, I believe you need to give it a hint about your intent via a comment. (In fairness, I don't think this is well-documented; I've only been able to find a tangential reference to this being a thing [here,](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) and only in the Scala version of the example.)

For example, I'm able to get my command to parse by writing:

```
%sql
-- `USING HIVE`
CREATE TABLE narf LIKE poit
```

Now, I *don't* have Hive Support enabled on my session, so my query fails... but it does parse!

---

**Edit:** Since your SQL statement is in a Python string, you can use a [multi-line string](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to use the single-line comment syntax, like this:

```
sparkSession.sql("""
  -- `USING HIVE`
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE B LIKE A
""")
```

There's also a delimited comment syntax in SQL, e.g.

```
sparkSession.sql("/* `USING HIVE` */ CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE B LIKE A")
```

which may work just as well.

Comment: I tried this within the spark-sql shell and it also works for me. But I can't use `sparkSession.sql("-- USING HIVE")` within pyspark.

Comment: `/* USING HIVE */` might work. The only reason I can think of for `-- USING HIVE` to not work is that it's a single-line comment, but writing a line break (`"\n"`) or using a multi-line string (`"""-- USING HIVE ... """`) should do it, too.